# Чи є український відповідник до словосполучення "приватне повідомлення"?

Tags: терміни, from-english, одним-словом

При користуванні веб-ресурсами і соцмережами, розділяють два види повідомлень: **загальнодоступні**, які видні іншим особам, і **приватні**, які доступні лише відправникові і отримувачу.

В англійській для цього використовується відприкметниковий іменник <sub>англ.</sub>*private*, у значенні *„private message“*. Але треба зауважити, що словосполучення *„to write in private“* [також має значення](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in--private) *«повідомити по секрету»*, тому вживання його одного, без уточнення „message“, виглядає обґрунтованим.

У російській є доволі поширений жаргонізм <sub>рос.</sub>*«личка»*, утворене скороченням від *«личное сообщение»*.

**Чи є подібне слово в українській?**
Особисто я у такому випадку використовую кальку з англійської *«приват»* *(«написати у приват»)*, але сподіваюся, що існують кращі варіанти.

[image: На картинці покупець запитує «Кілько тіво кури?», на що продавчиня відповідає «В лічьку написала».]
<sub>Картинка демонструє незручність використання прямої кальки з російської.</sub>

Comment: Личный — личка, приватний — приват. Може і калька з англійської, але вписується доволі органічно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Власне*, я іноді, коли не хочеться вживати латинізми чи запозичення з інших мов, використовую `повідомити особисто`, `написати особисте повідомлення`, `написати в особисті`.

Взагалі синонімічний ряд [`приватний`](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryvatnyj)-[`особистий`](http://sum.in.ua/s/osobystyj)-[`власний`](http://sum.in.ua/s/vlasnyj) має [достатньо відтінків](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53394/26148.html):

> *ПРИВАТНИЙ* Який належить окремій особі (особам); не державний, не суспільний.  [...] Який стосується окремої особи (осіб); особистий.
>
> **ОСОБИСТИЙ** [...] Який безпосередньо стосується якої-небудь особи, пов'язаний з нею. [...] Який здійснюється безпосередньо, не через інших осіб.
>
> *ВЛАСНИЙ* Належний кому-, чому-небудь за правом власності.

Comment: Ще: персональний, індивідуальний.

Comment: «Повідомити особисто» — логічно, але, з іншого боку, це можна інтерпретувати і як «сам повідомив».

Answer (score 2):

Якщо загалом, то зазвичай поширена калька *приватка* або скоротка *ПП*, що походить від *приватне повідомлення*. Також можна загадати усталене [*пиши*] [*напряму*](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83) як *звернутися прямо* — що збіжно з *direct* — один з сінонімів до *private* [*message*].

---

Якщо вдатися в роздуми і умовність, то ось що маю.

На мою думку, *особистий*, що часто наводять, в тому числі тут, не підходить, бо це стосується насамперед не слову *приватний*, а *персональний*, пак легко виводиться *особа* до *персона*. Етімолоґічний словник лише підтверджує цього:

> [ОСО́БА](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0)
>
> - псл. *osobь* «осібно, окремо», що виникло з прислівникового звороту *o sobě*, *o sebě* «окремо, сам собі»;
> - пор. і лат. *persona* «персона» з *per se* «про себе»;

Мені більше до смаку буде щось на зразок *окремка* — від *окремий*, що в свою чергу — є одним з і, хочу в це вірити, влучним антонімом до *загальний*. Вжиток теж додає ваги: *повідомити загалу* — *повідомити окремо*, *окремим особам*, *окремій особі*. Тут також можна виокремити ще одну перевагу над *особистий* — воно не прикріплене до певної особи (нп. і зазвичай до *тебе*) і може стосуватися будь-кого, майже будь-чого, втч. ґрупі: *приватне коло* — *окреме коло* (не як *особисте* — *твоє*, а як *закрите коло*).

Ще один зі слів може бути *обмежений*, що в декотрих контекстах може лягати навіть краще за попереднє: *обмежено повідомити комусь*, *обмежене товариство* ітд. З неприємного, слова з пнем *обмеж* можуть мати неприємну конотацію.

---

Але все ж таки *private message*, що також може бути *personal* чи *direct*, тут зазвичай розуміють як *віч-на-віч*, а не щось *виокремлене*, тому згадане *особистий* для таких випадках цілком підходить. До цього слова буде розмовне [*осібка*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B2+%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83%22), що вже має непоганий вжиток.

Answer (score -1):

Якщо питання стосується літературно правильного варіанту, максимально вільного від іншомовних запозичень, то «особисте повідомлення», «написати в особисті». 
Якщо ви шукаєте українського літературно правильного (але при цьому сленгового) відповідника для сленгового ж «приват», «лічка», то ви хочете неможливого: сленг неможливо сконструювати умоглядно зі словником у руках, має бути середовище носіїв (які мають і розмовляти чистою літературно правильною українською, і не бути при цьому відрваним від світу гуртком філологів, і користуватись інтернетом, і не зазнавати його русифікаторського/англізаторського впливу, починаючи з іншомовних інтерфейсів…), у якому цей сленг формується й розповсюджується. Все решта — особисте лінгвоконструкторство без опори на достовірні джерела.